# How to cast from boolean to integer using XQuery?

Tags: xquery, osb

I tried:

```
{ xs:integer($contentAssetProvider/text()) }
```

and

```
{ data($contentAssetProvider) cast as xs:integer? }
```

but getting

```
Error executing the XQuery transformation: Error parsing XML: {err}XP0021: "false": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer: error: decimal: Invalid decimal value: unexpected char '102'
```

I'll appreciate any input. Thanks

Comment: Solved with:   { xs:integer(xs:boolean(data($homepageAssetProvider))) }

Comment: So write as an answer and mark as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with: 
    { xs:integer(xs:boolean(data($homepageAssetProvider))) }